# Authentication Active Directory without LDAP

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I need to make an authentication against Active Directory without LDAP protocol in PHP. I always used LDAP so I'm a little of miss here. Could you provide some info? I have the Active Directory User, password, ou, dc and cn.